state space descretization of covariance matrix propagation
The descretization of a state space model is well defined. I understand that this descretization results in the same state vector values at the sample instants -- so long as the input is constant between samples. There are also methods to descretize the continuous covariance propagation between samples. The key issue is how to handle the noise covariance for the stochastic system. Gelb's book (Applied Optimal Estimation) shows that
Qk_dot = F Qk + Qk F^T + Q where Q is the noise strength for the continuous system and Qk is the noise variance for the discrete system. When I use this DE for Qk, I find that the state covariances dont match. Is there a way to find a Qk so that the discrete and continue covariances match at sample instants?

Hi. Please edit your formulas. MathJax tutorial
